# Различные положения экранов для разных устройств

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Появилась проблема, заключающаяся в том, чтобы ограничить положение изображения на экране. Если конкретно, то нужно, чтобы на tablet/phablet устройствах приложение работало в landscape режиме, а на всех остальных - в portrait режиме. Как это можно реализовать? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14793611/2082873

Comment: @Werder спасибо, можете написать в качестве ответа, чтобы я закрыл вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, готово

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ресурсах для разных размеров экранов вы можете создать файл для хранения булевских переменных, и для смартфона хранить `false`, а для планшетов `true`. Далее в активити вызывать метод  `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` проверяя перед этом значение и файле. Хороший пример [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793611/2082873)