# Можно ли каким-либо способом запретить смену ориентации для устройства определённого размера (small, normal)?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-layout

Доброго времени суток!

Моё приложение состоит из одного функционального Activity, в котором смена контента заключается в смене Fragment-ов. В Layout-файле самого Activity почти ничего нет (Toolbar, иконка загрузки, FAB), все основные элементы располагаются в Layout-ах фрагментов. 
Теперь непосредственно вопрос. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы:

1. На устройствах одного размера (в моём случаи **small и normal**) смена ориентации была **запрещена** (точнее, разрешена только портретная)...
2. ...но при этом на устройствах другого размера (**large и xlarge**) смена ориентации была **разрешена**? Или, как вариант, разрешена только land ориентация.

Способ подойдёт любой, хотя желательно, конечно, декларативный (через манифест или файлы проекта). Ну и желательно без костылей по-типу "программная смена ориентации в OnCreate при обнаружении устройства какого-то размера".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Различные положения экранов для разных устройств](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512916/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2)

Comment: @Werder да, дубликат (честно, не нашёл его, когда искал). Но здесь дали намного более удобное и качественно решение, которое предложил xkor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с `setRequestedOrientation` в `onCreate` имеет один неприятный эффект. Если пользователь держал устройство в ориентации которую вы хотите запретить, то при запуске приложения не смотря на вызов `setRequestedOrientation` на короткое время успеет создастся активити с лайаутом для тукущей, а не нужной конфигурацией и если у вас он сильно отличается между конфигурациями и вы начнете работать с ним как с правильным лайаутом, то возможно словите краш. Ну и даже без краша будет визуально некрасиво что сначала приложение покажется в текущей ориентации и тут же перевернется в правильную.

Через манифест к сожалению не сделать разные ориентации для разных типов устройств, но можно немного схитрить. Можно унаследовать от вашей основной активити (будем звать её BaseMainActivity) две другие (назовем их PhoneMainActivity и TabletMainActivity), в которых ничего нового делать не будем, они нужны только для того что бы в манифесте прописать для них разные ориентации. Так же нам понадобиться отдельная активит с которой приложение будет запускаться (назовем её SplashActivity), на ней можно какуюнить загрузочную картинку показывать, или закрывать сразу в `onCreate`, главное что в ней нужно сделать это проверить тип устройства и в зависимости от него запустить PhoneMainActivity или TabletMainActivity.

Answer (score 4):

В `onCreate` вашей `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   super.onCreate(bundle);

   if (isLargeDevice(getBaseContext())) {
        // land или портретная          
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

        // если надо только land         
        this.setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
   } else {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }
}
```

Ну и метод проверки:

```
private boolean isLargeDevice(Context context) {
        int screenLayout = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
        screenLayout &= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        switch (screenLayout) {
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                return false;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
}
```